# SSLSocketFactory and TrustManager redundancy in OkHttp3

Tags: java, okhttp, sslsocketfactory, x509trustmanager

In OkHttp3, the following is deprecated ***[A]***:

```
    sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory)
```

It is replaced by ***[B]***:

```
    sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory, X509TrustManager trustManager).
```

Here are my questions:

- What is the use of **X509TrustManager** in ***[B]*** ?
- What are the advantages of using ***[B]*** rather than ***[A]*** when a TrustManager can already be specified when creating a **SSLSocketFactory** object?
- In https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#sslSocketFactory-javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory-
  they talk about avoiding reflection when using ***[B]***, could somebody explain?

---

More info:

When creating a **SSLSocketFactory** object, it is already possible to specify a trustManager in

```
sslContext.init(KeyManager[] arg0, TrustManager[] arg1, SecureRandom arg2).
```

For example, I get a **SSLSocketFactory** object by doing:

```
public SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory() {
  SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
  sslContext.init(getKeyManager(), getTrustManager(), new SecureRandom());
  return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}
```

With ***getTrustManager*()** a method that returns a **TrustManager[]**, which contains the servers' certificate the client should trust.

Now, since

```
sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory, X509TrustManager trustManager)
```

expects me to provide a **X509TrustManager** object, I deal with this by doing:

```
OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory(), (X509TrustManager) getTrustManager()[0]).build();
```

However, I have the feeling this is not how they were expecting us to use it. So any inputs are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The method uses reflection. The reason is stated in the [OkHttp documentation](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-4.1.0/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.kt#L676-L692):

```
/**
 * Sets the socket factory used to secure HTTPS connections. 
 * If unset, the system default will be used.
 *
 * @deprecated [SSLSocketFactory] does not expose its [X509TrustManager], which is
 *     a field that OkHttp needs to build a clean certificate chain. This method
 *     instead must use reflection to extract the trust manager. Applications should
 *     prefer to call `sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory, X509TrustManager)`, 
 *     which avoids such reflection.
 */
```